# Get [X,Y] subset of an array

Tags: python, list, subset

I have the following array:

```
a1 = [
    0.00646424,
    0.00589349,
    0.00514049,
    0.00516998,
    0.00568154,
    0.00528288,
    0.00503256,
    0.00430429
]
```

How can I get a subset of this array in a variable where X is the start index and Y is the end index, where I can set X,Y on my own.

For example subset (3,5) would be:

`a2= [ 0.00516998, 0.00568154, 0.00528288]`

Comment: `a2=a1[3:6]`......

Comment: This is not an array, this is a **list**.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> a = [0.00646424, 0.00589349, 0.00514049, 0.00516998, 0.00568154, 0.00528288, 0.00503256, 0.00430429]
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 9 
>>> a[x:y]
[0.00528288, 0.00503256, 0.00430429]
>>>
```